# Yii2 debugger formato ilegible de objetos

Tags: yii2

Cuando traceamos un objeto es bastante engorroso tratar de descifrar los arrays tal y como los visualiza el debugger de Yii.

```
[ unserialize('O:17:"app\\models\\Modelo":8:{s:3 [...]
```

Es un galimatías ilegible. Lo ideal sería que se mostrasen de manera estructurada (con la información bien indentada en sus diferentes niveles) por ejemplo tal y como lo hace FirePHP.

```
array( [0] => app\models\Modelo(
    _attributes = array(
    ['mod_id'] => 1
    ['mod_nombre'] => 1
    [...]
```

Sin embargo FirePHP tampoco es perfecto ya que cuando lo copy-pasteas a un editor de texto pierdes la indentación y te queda tal que así.

```
array(
[0] =>
app\models\Modelo(
_attributes = array(
['mod_id'] => 1
['mod_nombre'] => 1
[...]
```

Si hacemos ...

```
Yii::warning(print_r($miModelo, true), 'Debugger');
```

... ya lo vemos mejor en el Debugger pero sigue sin poder copy-pastearse sin perder la indentación (además de verse peor en la consola de FirePHP).

También he probado con '<pre></pre>' envolviendo print_r($miModelo, true), ... pero sin éxito. En otros frameworks lo solucionábamos así.

En fin, la cuestión resumida es conocer si hay alguna forma de ver los objetos claramente indentados y con capacidad de copy-pastear esta representación indentada.

Habitualmente, en objetos muy grandes, es muy práctico poder copy-pastear la representación indentada del objeto para cotejar entre varias versiones, realizar búsquedas, ... No me puedo creer que nos tengamos que conformar, ¿cómo solucionáis este tema vosotros?.

Gracias.

Comment: tengo tiempo sin trabajar en yii2 pero has intentado usar el [export dump](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basevardumper.html#export()-detail)?

Comment: `VarDumper::dump($var);` tampoco se ajusta a las necesidades.

Comment: no me refiero al metodo dump, sino al VarDumper::export() probaste usando el método export _?

Comment: export devuelve un string simple. ´VarDumper::dump($this, 100, true);´ es más aproximado a lo que busco porque que se ve indentado y se copy-pastea perfectamente ... pero le falta poder integrarse con el debugger de Yii tal que así ´Yii::warning(VarDumper::dump($this, 100, true), 'traceo');´. La idea es poder trabajar sólo con el debugger, sin necesidad de imprimir en la misma aplicación ni utilizar die-s.